# receiving current width during an animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to know the current width during an animation of the width. How can I log the current width, I need it to adjust another element.

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z74LR/)

jquery

```
$( "#box" ).animate({
        width:400
    }, 600 );

console.log(currentWidth);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `step` function:

```
$("#box").animate({
    width: 400
}, {
    duration: 600,
    step: function (now, fx) {
      // console.log(now)
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z74LR/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can use callback:

```
$( "#box" ).animate({
    width:400
}, 600,function(){
    console.log($(this).width());
});
```

Comment: The callback function is executed when the animation is complete, the question is "receiving current width _during_ an animation".